# Plot bar chart with specific range of x axis in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot, bar-chart, matlab-figure

I would like to plot a bar chart like below in MATLAB. Any one know which function should I use? Many thanks in advance!

1. The bar is specified with range in x (some may be wider than others).
2. There is no line between two bars (red cross in the figure).
3. X axis is in log scale.

[image: bar]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why don't you try to do it with the `plot` or `semilogx` function?

```
x = [0.1 0.18 0.18 0.32 0.32 0.56 0.56 1.0];
y = [30 30 25 25 110 110 80 80];
semilogx(x,y);
```

[image: matlab figure]

and if you want the x ticks like in your figure you can set them on the axis object:

```
ax = gca;
ax.XTick = unique(x);
ax.XTickLabel = unique(x);
```

[image: matlab fig with xticks]